# JSQMessagesViewController + Firebase (3.4.0)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I recently updated my project from Firebase **(2.5.1)** to Firebase **(3.4.0)** by installing the following in my Podfile:

**pod** 'Firebase/Database'

**pod** 'Firebase/Core'

**pod** 'Firebase/Auth'

With that being said, I updated my project according to the **FirebaseDatabase** documentation since my app mainly uses real-time database and authentication.

At the moment I'm experiencing some very tricky errors and I have not been able to work through the following:

```
private func observeMessages() {
    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(25)
    messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

        let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as! String
        let text = snapshot.value!["text"] as! String

        self.addMessage(id, text: text)

        self.finishReceivingMessage()
    })
}
```

[I've tried fixing it to the best of my ability to no avail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kt7DT.png)
[and my app keeps crashing due to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DA9Pt.png)

I didn't have this problem when I had **Firebase (2.5.1)** in my podfile so I'm certain its attributed to the new update.

If anyone could kindly advise me on how to navigate through this error, please feel free to comment and offer any kind of suggestions in relation to this issue. Thank you.

***8/25/16***

**Solution:**

```
private func observeMessages() {
    let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(25)
    messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
        if let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as? String, text = snapshot.value!["text"] as? String {
        self.addMessage(id, text: text)
        self.finishReceivingMessage()
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You might want to delete the app off your phone and simulator and run again.

Comment: It's not my phone, it's the Xcode simulator itself. @PeterdeVries

Comment: that's why I did mention simulator, did you try? And even 'Reset Content and Settings'

Comment: My apologies, I read too fast. It didn't work. Reset both simulator and iPhone, still have the same errors.

Comment: in that case I think the problem is not in your func observeMessages(), as I use the same code, (be it spread out over various) and mine works.

Comment: What version of Firebase? Because I just tested it out again on 2.5.1 and everything works as it should.

Comment: my version is 3.4.0

Comment: @Alex7 can I check your firebase structure and data???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

```
private func observeMessages() {
let messagesQuery = messageRef.queryLimitedToLast(25)
messagesQuery.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot!) in
    if let id = snapshot.value!["senderId"] as? String, text = snapshot.value!["text"] as? String {
    self.addMessage(id, text: text)
    self.finishReceivingMessage()
      }
    }
  }
```